# Open all hyperlinks on a given page in new tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to open all links on a given webpage in new tabs at once using JavaScript. Lets take the Stack Overflow question list as an example. Here is what I came up with:

```
$(".question-hyperlink").each(function(){

 $(this).attr({
           target: "_blank",
           title: "Opens in a new window"
       });
 $(this).click();

})
```

Unfortunately this does not work at all. I tried using `window.open` instead, but still no success. How can I do it?

Comment: What happens after execution? Do you see added attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) does not simulate a click by the user, it just fires all the event handlers bound to the click event. So it only runs the JS code you have put in place, and not the browsers reaction to the click.

You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) like this:

```
$(".question-hyperlink").each(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), '_blank');
});
```

Watch out for pop-up blockers though! If you want to handle them, you can do something like this:

```
var x = window.open(...);
if(x) {
   //The window was opened.
}
else {
   //It was blocked.
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I actually did this, but forgot about checking for popup blockers when testing. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Unscrupulous spammers would love to be able to make visitors' browsers open a large number of links in new windows at the same time. They'd happily open a dozen pages that the user doesn't want to see and then claim the click-through advertising money.

The user of the browser wouldn't be so happy with this though, so most browsers make it impossible for you to open multiple windows at once.

What you want cannot be done.

Comment: That depends on the context. If this functionality is desired for a environment where you have control over browser settings (like for a chrome JS extenstion, or a JS app on a company intranet where you are in charge of the settings) you might be able to do it. However, to rely on it to work for all users on the web might not be a good idea.